# Why would LINE login recommend OAuth 2.0 implicit flow through their SDK for native apps over Authorization Code flow?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect

Recently, I'm trying to use OAuth 2.0 to support handy sign in/up feature using LINE login and Sign In With Apple in my native app(iOS).

You might be unfamiliar with LINE, it is a company running LINE messenger with 200M+ MAUs.

As you know, there are Authorization Code grant flow and implicit flow in OAuth 2.0 to get access token from Auth server.

Apple(and many other OAuth 2.0 providers) mostly supports Authorization Code grant flow because it is safer than implicit flow and better in that you can also get refresh token, not only access token. So, as far as I know, Authorization Code flow is more recommended way to get access token in OAuth 2.0([RFC also says that here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-8.2)).

> However, as the implicit flow cannot be protected by PKCE [RFC7636]
> (which is required in Section 8.1), the use of the Implicit Flow with
> native apps is NOT RECOMMENDED.

However, according to LINE's developer documentation, they don't recommend authorization procedure in Web Apps, where Authorization Code flow comes in, for Native Apps.

> We strongly recommend building your LINE Login integration with a LINE SDK if it's available for your development environment. We don't recommend using the procedure described in this page for native apps. For more information on using a LINE SDK, see Integrating with native apps.

(from Notes in https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/line-login/integrate-line-login/#page-title)

Using their SDK, if user clicks their login button, LINE app's auth screen launches and they redirect us to our apps page using universal link after authorization process.
And they give us access token directly, not Authorization Code, as a callback parameter.

Here is sample code from [LINE docs](https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/ios-sdk/swift/integrate-line-login/#use-code),

```swift
// LoginViewController.swift

import LineSDK

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {    
    func login() {
        LoginManager.shared.login(permissions: [.profile], in: self) {
            result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let loginResult):
                print(loginResult.accessToken.value) // We can get accessToken from loginResult
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a diagram of OAuth 2.0 and OIDC flow for native apps in LINE login.
[image: Diagram of OAuth 2.0 flow for native apps in LINE login]
[image: Diagram of OIDC flow for native apps in LINE login]
(from https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/line-login/secure-login-process/)

Why would they use implicit flow for OAuth 2.0 login?

Maybe they thought it is safe because they are instructing us to always call access token/id token verification API before we use it?

Am I missing something? I don't think they would recommend bad solutions because they are quite big tech company with many skillful engineers.

I just guessed that they intentionally designed their login procedure for native apps like this because they already recognizes the presence of Authorization Code flow which is what they are using for web apps).

I'm just guessing they might have thought it would be ok if our servers always call id token verification API to get user's information(or access token verification API before using it), not using data parsed from id token itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything. Being a large company doesn't mean that they will make everything right. The security recommendations from OAuth experts are quite clear on this one - using implicit flow is less secure than using code flow with PKCE. Maybe LINE's recommendation are outdated and at the time of writing they found it more secure.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I'm just guessing that they might have thought it would be ok if our servers always call id token verification API to get user's information(or access token verification API before using it), not using data parsed from id token itself. Would it be wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, for some reason they don't want to let you use the data in the id token directly (maybe they don't want to release it to the client).

Comment: Yeah, I mean, requiring always to verify id token/access token might mitigate less secure characteristics of implicit flow?

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell without a deep security analysis. They decided to go with some non-standard solution. We use standards in the industry so that we know how to mitigate attacks, as many experts have thought about the standard before and the dangers of implementations. If you have a non-standard solution you don't know what are the dangers or whether anyone has given it a good thought when designing this solution.